In ASP.NET Core MVC, appsettings.json, how do I get value from static class?
I have a new ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project using Visual Studio 2022.
In appsettings.json, I have a connection string:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDB": "...connecting...details...."
}

I can use dependency injection in my controllers to read this value:
 private IConfiguration _AppSettingsConfig; 

 public PocController(IConfiguration config)
 {
     _AppSettingsConfig = config;
 }

and then use it
_AppSettingsConfig.GetConnectionString("MyDB")

or
_AppSettingsConfig["ConnectionStrings:MyDB"];

That works, however, I want to replace these 5 lines with a class that contains a static property that will wrap around this and return the appsettings.json value.
public class ConfigProps
{
    public static string MyDBConString
    {
        get 
        { 
            return "how do I get from here to the config?";
        }
    }
}

Is there a way to do this?

Why would you want to do that?

You could still get it by using the ConfigurationBuilder to load the json file and then read it by using the GetConnectionString method.
More detials you could refer to below codes:
public class ConfigProps
{
    private static readonly IConfiguration _config;

    static ConfigProps()
    {
        _config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
    }

    public static string MyDBConString
    {
        get
        {
            return _config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        }
    }
}

Result:


Will that use the cached data from appsettings.json file, or will it read it from new?

Cached data by default, if you want to reload when the appsetting.json and you could set the  reloadOnChange: true for it.

reloadOnChange didn't work, but the main answer you provided works like a charm. It does keep the values as they are until the next rebuild. I haven't tested what happens when there are values that override the settings per environment. Thank you!
